# Bundling ImageMagick in py2app

Tags: python, imagemagick, py2app, wand

I am trying to make a py2app that uses Imagemagick
`from wand.image import Image`
The import works fine on my machine, but causes the following error when trying to launch the app on others:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "wand/api.pyc", line 151, in <module>
  File "wand/api.pyc", line 140, in load_library
OSError: cannot find library; tried paths: []

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/jcampana/Downloads/HEIC Sweeper/HEIC Sweeper.app/Contents/Resources/__boot__.py", line 110, in <module>
    _run()
  File "/Users/jcampana/Downloads/HEIC Sweeper/HEIC Sweeper.app/Contents/Resources/__boot__.py", line 84, in _run
    exec(compile(source, path, "exec"), globals(), globals())
  File "/Users/jcampana/Downloads/HEIC Sweeper/HEIC Sweeper.app/Contents/Resources/converter.py", line 7, in <module>
    from wand.image import Image
  File "wand/image.pyc", line 18, in <module>
  File "wand/assertions.pyc", line 155, in <module>
  File "wand/color.pyc", line 10, in <module>
  File "wand/api.pyc", line 177, in <module>

>ImportError: MagickWand shared library not found.
You probably had not installed ImageMagick library.
Try to install:
  brew install freetype imagemagick
2021-03-29 20:19:21.001 converter[3593:128301] converter Error
```

To fix this, I tried including Wand in the setup.py options field `"packages":"wand"` as well as including all the site packages using the command: `python3 setup.py py2app --site-packages` but neither was successful. Any help including the module in the .app bundle would be greatly appreciated.

Note: I have other dependencies such as `from watchdog.observers import Observer` that seem to bundle fine

Comment: The python wand library doesn't include the ImageMagick libraries, and linked delegate libraries & binaries. You'll need to bundle those & dynamically build `MAGICK_HOME` + `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` on launch.

Comment: Thank you for your help! So to include ImageMagick libraries and linked libraries/binaries I would add them to the setup.py options? How do I go about dynamically building `MAGICK_HOME` + `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` on launch?